# Android Horizontal Progress Bar Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar

I have a little problem with my Dialog created in my Synchronization activity. I need to show to the user the progress of the downloading and the current connection speed in Kb/Mb. But that's my first try with Horizontal Progress Bar and I'm not really familiar how to do that. So any kind of help/suggestions/advices are welcomed. I'll be really happy if you help me to understand this!

Thanks!

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the API demos for alert dialogs? It contains a progress bar dialog, so may be helpful:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html